# Distinct results from Spring Data JPA Specification that uses join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have the following `Specification` that I use to query for any `Contact` entities that are tied to certain `ManagedApplication` entities. I pass in a `Collection<Long>` that contains the ids of the `ManagedApplication` entities that I am searching for.

```
public static Specification<Contact> findByApp(final Collection<Long> appIds) {
    return new Specification<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {            
            final Predicate appPredicate = root.join(Contact_.managedApplications)
                .get(ManagedApplication_.managedApplicationId).in(appIds);
        }
    }
}
```

I pass this specification to the `.findAll()` method of my `PagingAndSoringRepository` to retrieve a `Page<Contact>` that will contain all `Contact` entities that meet the search criteria.

Here is the `Repository`.

```
@Repository
public interface PagingAndSortingContactRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contact, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Contact> {    
}
```

And here is how I'm calling the `.findAll()` method.

```
final Page<Contact> contacts = pagingAndSortingContactRepository.findAll(ContactSpecification.findByApp(appIds), pageable);
```

This works and returns all `Contact` entities that are tied to any of the `ManagedApplication` entities that correspond to the ids passed in. However, since I am calling `.join()` to join the `Contact` entity with the `ManagedApplication` entity, if one `Contact` has multiple `ManagedApplication` entities in the list of app ids, then the query will return duplicate `Contact` entities.

So what I need to know is, how can I get only distinct `Contact` entities returned from my query using this `Specification`?

I know that `CriteriaQuery` has a `.distinct()` method that you can pass a boolean value to, but I am not using the `CriteriaQuery` instance in the `toPredicate()` method of my `Specification`.

Here are the relevant sections of my metamodels.

Contact_.java:

```
@StaticMetamodel(Contact.class)
public class Contact_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Contact, String> firstNm;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Contact, String> lastNm;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Contact, String> emailAddress;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Contact, ManagedApplication> managedApplications;
    public static volatile SetAttribute<Contact, ContactToStructure> contactToStructures;
}
```

ManagedApplication_.java

```
@StaticMetamodel(ManagedApplication.class)
public class ManagedApplication_ {
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<ManagedApplication, Integer> managedApplicationId;
}
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the `query` parameter in your `toPredicate` method to invoke the distinct method.

Sample below:

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {            
    final Predicate appPredicate = root.join(Contact_.managedApplications)
        .get(ManagedApplication_.managedApplicationId).in(appIds);
    query.distinct(true);
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it works great!

Also, to clarify, you have to add the `query.distinct(true)` to every predicate that needs this distinct statement. Its not sufficient to just add this statement to any predicate and have it work for the entire query..

Comment: How does this work? I mean, if you use plain MySQL syntax to join some tables that form a many to many relationship so that you can select the rows of the left table which have a certain value in a column of the right table, although you use a SELECT DISTINCT clause you still get duplicated results if a row in the left table is related to more than one row in the right table.

Comment: It seems that manipulating the `query` parameter in a `Specification` is [discouraged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2126#issuecomment-752569941) and [unsupported](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2126#issuecomment-752569947) by the devs. But I don't have a better solution to offer.

Answer (score 28):

a new static method could be added

```
public static Specification<Object> distinct() {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        query.distinct(true);
        return null;
    };
}
```

where later you could add when creating your Specification

```
Specification.where(
    YourStaticClassWhereYouCreatedTheUpperMethod.distinct().and(..))
```

Comment: Don't forget! Oracle DB does not like distinct with LOB types :)