# how to retrieve only distinct entities by a specific column using Spring Data Specification

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I need to find the only FlightSeat entities that don't share the common flight(flight.id).
That is one FlightSeat per Flight.
If I get list of FlightSeats using current implementation there are FlightSeats tied to the same Flight.

I tried adding this but it didn't help

```java
public class FlightSearchSpecification {
    // getSeatSpecification()

    public static Specification<Object> distinct() {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            query.distinct(true);
            return null;
        };
    }
}


flightSeatRepository.findAll(Specification
    .where(FlightSearchSpecification.distinct().and(FlightSearchSpecification.getSeatSpecification(model))) , pageable);
```

Maybe it can be achieved by groupBy() but I can't understand how to do that.

**Classes**

Speicification

```java
public class FlightSearchSpecification {
  
    public static Specification<FlightSeat> getSeatSpecification(TicketFilterModel model) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {

            Join<FlightSeat, Flight> join = root.join("flight");
            Join<Flight, AviaCompany> join2 = join.join("company");

            Predicate whereSeatClass = cb.equal(root.get("seatClass"), model.getSeatClass());
            Predicate whereSource = cb.equal(join.get("source"), model.getSource());
            Predicate whereDestination = cb.equal(join.get("destination"), model.getDestination());
            Predicate whereCompanyName = join2.get("name").in(model.getCompanies());
            Predicate WhereCustomerNull = cb.isNull(root.get("customer"));

            return cb.and(
                    whereSeatClass, whereSource,
                    whereDestination, whereCompanyName, WhereCustomerNull);
        };
    }
}
```

JPA Repository

```java
public interface FlightSeatRepository extends JpaRepository<FlightSeat, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<FlightSeat> {

    List<FlightSeat> findByFlightId(Long flightId);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"flight", "flight.company"})
    Page<FlightSeat> findAll( Specification<FlightSeat> spec,  Pageable pageable);

}
```

Usage of the specification in .findAll()

```java
flightSeatRepository.findAll(FlightSearchSpecification.getSeatSpecification(model), pageable);
```

FlightSeat Entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "flight_seats")
public class FlightSeat {

    @Column(name = "flight_seat_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int position;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int price;

    @Column(name = "class", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @JsonProperty("seat_class")
    private FlightSeatClass seatClass;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "flight_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Flight flight;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Customer customer;

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Flight Entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "flights")
@Immutable
public class Flight {

    @Column(name = "flight_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "airplane_model", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(value = "airplane_model")
    private String airplaneModel;

    @Column(name = "takeoff_timestamp", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(value = "takeoff_timestamp")
    private ZonedDateTime takeoffTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "landing_timestamp", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(value = "landing_timestamp")
    private ZonedDateTime landingTimestamp;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private City source;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private City destination;

    @Column(name = "seat_count")
    @JsonProperty(value = "seat_count")
    private int seatCount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "avia_company_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private AviaCompany company;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "flight")
    @JsonIgnore
    private final Set<FlightSeat> seats = new HashSet<>();

    // constructor, getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distinct results from Spring Data JPA Specification that uses join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025213/distinct-results-from-spring-data-jpa-specification-that-uses-join)

Comment: I already tried it, but it didn't help.

Comment: Moreover the column the entities must be distinct by is not even specified. And I don't understand where it should be specified